# Can context-param be referenced inside web.xml?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

Can I reference context parameter in a DD itself?
For instance:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>firstParam</param-name>
    <param-value>/first</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>firstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>${firstParam}</url-pattern>
</servlet_mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ,  it is not possible. There is no such feature.