# Context-params use inside the web.xml

Tags: java, web.xml, context-param

Is there a way to use the context-params inside the web.xml

example

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>AUTH_SERVER</param-name>
    <param-value>10.126.35.10</param-value>
</context-param>
...

<filter>
    <filter-name>NtlmHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        AUTH_SERVER
    </init-param>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement the filter probably you have to read the `<init-param>` parameter of the filter. There, instead of reading the parameter of the filter, you can read directly the context param, using:

```
filterConfig.getServletContext().getInitParameter("paramName");
```

Does that solve your matter?

Comment: My problem is generated due to the fact that I need to authenticate the user on access, using ntlm and then I need to use those credentials to authorize the use depending on his selection further on. I know how to access the context-param in code, but I do not know if there's a way o access them inside the web.xml

Comment: The feature you describe is not possible. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575015/can-context-param-be-referenced-inside-web-xml